# mutateAsync data is undefined in submit event (react query)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I am currently trying to make a request to my API using React Query. When I log my data inside the component function scope it logs fine and gives the data I expect, it also logs the correct data before the `handleSubmit` does. When I log my data variable inside `handleSubmit`, after submitting, it always logs undefined.

```
// useSignup.ts

import axios from "axios";
import { useMutation } from "react-query";

const signup = (credidentials: any) => {
    return axios.post("/api/signup", credidentials);
};

const useSignup = () => {
    return useMutation(signup);
};

export default useSignup;
```

```
// Signup.tsx

const {
    mutateAsync: makeApiRequest,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
    data: authData,
} = useSignup();

console.log(authData); // Updates fine and gives the correct data

const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await makeApiRequest(input);
    console.log(authData); // Always undefined
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `awaiting` `makeApiRequest` does not, in the same event handler, make data from the hook "defined" right after that. It's similar to:

```
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(undefined)

<button onClick={() => {
  setCount(1)
  console.log(count)
}) />
```

here, logging the count will *also* be `undefined`, as it will only be set to `1` in the next render cycle. being `async` doesn't change that - this is just how react works.

if you want to access data *after* a successful submit, use the `onSuccess` callback of the `mutate` function:

```
makeApiRequest(input, { onSuccess: newData => console.log(newData) }
```

you can also use `mutateAsync`, which *returns* data from the mutation, but you need to catch errors manually and I don't think this is needed often.

Comment: Thank you very much. Someone answered exactly same somewhere else just a second ago. Appreciate the help!